# Passing an external file as an argument to a Kubernetes POD

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have a requirement of deploying a container in Kubernetes. The image that I have created expects certain arguments, one of which is a file that is placed at an external location, say Github.

How would I be able to mount the path of this external file so that when I deploy this container and pass the arguments and file can be passed to the container.

Currently, the complete path of the file is given

```
args: ["update","--changesetFile","https://github.com/lbg-gcp-foundation/ep-liquibase-db-propagation/blob/db-prop-pipeline/resources/release1.0/customer/ddl/db.changelog.customer.ddl.rel1.sql","--url=jdbc:cloudspanner:/projects/eplus-cus-02-ide-d08b/instances/spn-01/databases/spd-01","--labels","base","--tag","0.0.1-test"]
```

how to mount this path "https://github.com/lbg-gcp-foundation/ep-liquibase-db-propagation/blob/db-prop-pipeline/resources/release1.0/customer/ddl/db.changelog.customer.ddl.rel1.sql"

Comment: I guess its your private directory as I get 404. If this faile contains only text you can think about create [ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/). If this image was created by Dockerfile you can hardcode this in your image. Or it MUST be somehow mount in specific way?

Answer (score 0):

There was a thing called gitRepo as a mountable Volume, but that is deprecated now. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#gitrepo

As the link above states, you should use an init container to clone the repo an mount it as an emptyDir.

A curl might also be sufficient to get the file.

Comment: I am spinning up a pod through helm. The sql files that I wan to send as an argument are within the same workspace of the helm but at a location outside the chart directory.
I can create an empDir but how to place the sql files (which are at the location "src/main/resources/ddl/*sql" in the same workspace) in it before the pod comes up and refer to the volume mounted on empDir?
Please help me with this, if you have any solution.